# Radio button is selecting wrongly from data list in angular js and dynamic validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have data list which will display in the form of multiple radio buttons . each row will have 3 fields .

ex: row1:abc , 123 , xyz
   row2: xyz , 145 , xyz

now when i select radio button in first row it is selecting second row . How to make that radio row unique ?

```
        <label  ng-repeat="list in data">                                       
           <table>                                              
              <tr
                <td rowspan="2" >
                  <input type="radio"   name="select" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{list.name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {{list.number}}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  {{list.value}}
                </td>                                                    
              </tr>                                               
           </table>
```

Also how do I validate these fields , if they are comming as null I have display error message since it is dynamic data and this page is read only page .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the null validation you can use a conditional in a ng-bind directive and for selecting different values you need a different name for each row

```
<label  ng-repeat="list in data">                                       
           <table>                                              
              <tr
                <td rowspan="2" >
                  <input type="radio" ng-attr-name="{{'select' + list.number}}" />
                </td>
                <td ng-bind="{{list ? list.number: 'error name'}}">
                </td>
                <td ng-bind="{{list ? list.number: 'error number'}}">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td ng-bind="{{list ? list.value : 'error value'}}">                  
                </td>                                                    
              </tr>                                               
           </table>
```

I'm not sure if the ng-attr-name will work :( please let me know if this works

Comment: I am able to get selected data with ng-model=$parent.data from data list . But the problem is when there are unique name values the radio select is not happening expected way . instead of selecting one it is selecting other button bcoz of same name values . If i give unique name values then it is selecting properly .. validation yet to check .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
In html
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in list">
            <td>
                <input type="radio"  ng-model="val.value" value="{{$index}}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span  ng-show="data.name">{{data.name}}</span>
                <span  ng-hide="data.name">Error in name</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span  ng-show="data.number">{{data.number}}</span>
                <span  ng-hide="data.name">Error in number</span>
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </table>

In controller
$scope.val ={} // take this object this will store current row number
//$scope.val.value  // contain row number 
 var data =  $scope.list[$scope.val.value] // this will give u data at that row
```